# Create an object of class which has injected instance variable in java

Tags: java, dependency-injection, static, inject

I do have one class that has one instance variable, that is being injected like below:

```
public Class HierarchyAccessor {
  @Inject
  HierarchyProvider provider;

  public int GetAllHierarchies(HierarchyAccessorInput input) {
    String requiredVariable = input.getId;
    provider.provideHierarchy(requiredVariable);
  }
}
```

Here, I do have another class `HierarchyHelper`, that has one static function which is performing some operation by creating an object of class `HierarchyAccessor`.

```
public Class HierarchyHelper {
 public static List<String> getHierarchies() {
   // Here I want to create the object of HierarchyAccessor.
   // this is not working .
   HierarchyAccessor accessor = new HierarchyAccessor();
   
   /*
       It performs some operations and returns the required output.
   */
   
  }
}
```

So, here I'm unable to create the object of `HierarchyAccessor` class inside the static method, due to some constraint, I can't change this static method to non-static.

Can someone please suggest how to create the object of `HierarchyAccessor` inside the static method?

Comment: You mean that you can create the `HierarchyAccessor` but then `HierarchyProvider provider` is null right?

Comment: Since you have `@Inject` annotation it means you're using some Dependency Injection framework. My guess is Guice (you didn't give us any info about that). With DI framework you should not be manually creating objects (with new keyword) you should let DI framework to do it for you, i.e. with the usage of factories that you can obtain from framework.

Comment: @MirekPluta , Yes i have used Guice Framework .

Comment: @JoãoDias , Yes you're right , HierarchyProvider provider comes null , if i try to create object using new keyword .

Comment: You need to let guice create the whole hierarchy of objects. You can't be manually creating those objects that are controlled by the DI container, which leaves the conclusion: you need to redesign your application.

Comment: @MirekPluta , Can you suggest this via some code . How should i manually create the object .

Comment: You can't manually create a `HierarchyAccessor` object and expect that magically a `HierarchyProvider` object is injected. That is not how a DI framework works. So that such an object is injected you need to let the framework instantiate and manage all those objects.

Comment: @JoãoDias , agreed , so what should be the way to create object in this scenerio , could you please share some reference or suggest some way to do so ?

Comment: I never worked with Guice so I can't really help you with the details, but static things and DI frameworks do not go along very well, so as @MirekPluta already suggested, consider redesigning your application.